# Consuming a RESTful api with Restangular - Is it secure for a RESTful api to return an array as a top-level object?

Tags: javascript, json, security, rest, flask

I'm creating a RESTful web service using Python Flask. For one of my endpoints I'd like to return a list of users. The api endpoint returns JSON in the following format:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "Email": "email1@example.org",
      "First": "Tom",
      "Last": "Jones",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "Email": "email2@example.org",
      "First": "Steven",
      "Last": "Fry",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "Email": "email3@example.org",
      "First": "Monty",
      "Last": "Python",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

If I do this Restangular responds with

> Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or
>   something else

which is by design as Restangular expects an Array and not a Javascript object. From what I understand there are two preferred options for dealing with this:

**Option 1** - Wrap the response in an array like so:

```
[{
  "users": [
    {
      "Email": "email1@example.org",
      "First": "Tom",
      "Last": "Jones",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "Email": "email2@example.org",
      "First": "Steven",
      "Last": "Fry",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "Email": "email3@example.org",
      "First": "Monty",
      "Last": "Python",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}]
```

However, according to this article http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/security/#json-security this is not secure. Is my understanding correct here?

**Option 2** - The second option is to use this method: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case
In this case is it possible (would I need to?) to create an interceptor for every getList request on all endpoints that return multiple items e.g. a 'posts' endpoint, 'messages' endpoint etc.? Would this be a feasible or good approach?

Is there anything I'm missing in my understanding?

Option 1 seems like less work but potentially introduces a security concern. Option 2 would be more work but mitigates the potential security problem (if there is one).

If there's an even better 'Option 3' it would be great to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

You can set isArray equals false, and handle your request normally check https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/85